# why does one trapped signal cause another to repeat?

Tags: bash, signals

Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# this is repeat-signal.sh

trap "echo got USR1; wait" USR1
trap "echo got INT" INT

(
  kill -s USR1 $$
  sleep 100
) &

wait
```

When I run this by entering `./repeat-signal.sh`, it prints `"got USR1"` as expected. Then when I send the `INT` signal (either with ctrl+c or using `kill` from another terminal), it prints two lines:

```
got INT
got USR1
```

I was expecting it to only print `got INT`.

Why is the `got USR1` line printed when I send the `INT` signal? It seems as if the `INT` signal is somehow causing the `USR1` signal to be repeated.

Edit for clarification:

at the end, my terminal looks like this:

```
bash-5.0$ ./repeat-signal.sh
got USR1
^Cgot INT
got USR1
```

Edit 2:

Actually, this seems to happen in bash 3.2 but not bash 5.0

Comment: You try INT right after "got USR1" is received or do you start the script again and try INT?

Comment: I hit ctrl+c right after "got USR1" is printed

Comment: Unable to recreate the issue (Linux Mint 18.1). What OS version are you on? You probably should not have a wait inside a trap. In particular, what process do you expect this to wait for? The INT goes to both the shell running the script (knocking the trap USR1 off its wait) and also to the subshell containing the sleep, and the sleep itself.

Comment: Don't have such an old bash, but version 4 also doesn't give the second USR1.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what the issue here was exactly but I'm satisfied that I can fix it by upgrading bash. (I was on 3.2 because that's the version that came with macOS catalina). @Paul_Pedant I will probably ask a separate question about the `wait` - I'm sure I'm not doing something right there.

Comment: @dipea That may likely be a bug in older Bash but I would deem your USR1 handler a bug as well: why `wait` in a signal handler? good practices for signal handlers (in C language and even more in Bash) is to have them do something simple and certainly non-blocking. You usually want handlers to just set a flag which you will act upon later on within a kind of event-loop. For instance, at the end of your script do a `while wait` loop in place of the standalone `wait`.